# Debugging a flash stack overflow

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, debugging, actionscript, flexbuilder

I have a swf that is being loaded by a third party swf.  I have source code and recompile my swf, but don't have code to the third party swf.

Somewhere, likely in my code, there's a stack overflow.  In a debug flash player, I get a nice popup dialog with a stack trace when the overflow occurs:

```
Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
    at Object$/Object::_hasOwnProperty()
    at Object/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::hasOwnProperty()
    at Object$/Object::_hasOwnProperty()
    at Object/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::hasOwnProperty()
    at Object$/Object::_hasOwnProperty()
```

It goes on like this for 64 lines.  However, it looks like I'm only seeing the last 64 stack frames, not the whole stack trace.

Is there a way to see the full stack trace?  As an alternative, is there a way to limit the stack depth?

I've spent a full day trying to debug this, but am running on very little information, and a lack of tools.  Here's what I've tried:

- Hooking my code up to a debugger.  This is in flash 9.0.28 running in windows inside a VM, connecting to flex builder running outside the VM.  It appears to connect, but I don't get trace statements, and breakpoints don't fire.
- Sending log lines to an http server. This works, but I suspect I'm missing the last n stack frames before the overflow/server crash.
- A blind, binary search type approach disabling portions of code - this is slow, but probably will work.

Any other strategies I should be trying?

Comment: Newer versions of Flex Builder's debugger aren't fully compatible with Flash Player 9.0.28 anymore. I believe you need 9.0.115 or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-939?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) sounds like the same problem? Sorry as it's not directly an answer on how you could further debug this but more a pointer to someone who had a similar problem and found a solution.

Comment: The page you are linking to is hidden being a registration wall. Is the same information available somewhere else? Because right now, their registration server are down and like most developer, I'd rather try to fix my bug right now!